# SELECT * FROM games WHERE

Tags: mysql

I am having issues with my MySQL syntax. I would like to run a select query where either one of two options are true. However the following code does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE genre="indie" OR title="indie"
```

I have been fooling around and look at other threads and have found out how to use OR to check the same column for multiple entries but not a way to check different columns for the same entries. When I do:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE genre="indie"
```

The query works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should work perfectly fine. It doesn't work means error or returns wrong results? Try second option only - maybe that's problem in that column.

Comment: can you show the result expected and the result you got?

Comment: probably you want to write OR title LIKE '%indie%'

Comment: it should work fine. are you typing it in a gui tool like sqlyog or phpmy admin? if its in command line, you should put a semi-colon after the statement.

maybe you should check for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see this really would't work, is if you've mistyped the name of the column 'title' (if the second query you wrote works)

The assumptions about the case sensitivity are wrong, since the second query returns something, the first should return at least the same rows as the second one

In MySQL " " works just as ' ', so this assuption was wrong too.

If you post more information, it would be easier to help you

Comment: Made it in to see my professor today and this worked fine. I most likely had some sort of spelling error and wasn't noticing it. Was rather late.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you ignoring the upper/lower case? Also use `like`

You can use this:

`SELECT * FROM games WHERE (LOWER(genre) like 'indie') OR (LOWER(title) like 'indie')`

Comment: If that was the problem, the second query, that is working, would't work either

Comment: "Also use `like`" --- for what particular reason?

Comment: Some time ago my teacher said that for text I need to use `like`... well I am sticking to that pattern

Comment: @Andrew how can the like operator, which tends to compare text with a partial pattern, help evaluating mathematical expressions?

Comment: @Andrew: your teacher was wrong (or you didn't get what he exactly mean)